# Jquery hiding/unhiding on check box change not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, onchange

Forgive me for any bad habits, I've been playing with html and jquery for all of 48 hours.

I am attempting to hiding/unhide input fields based on which checkboxes are checked. And then hide all of the fields if the "None" box is checked.

I am having issues with the code below showing the input fields until the boxes have been checked/unchecked one time. Then they begin behaving like they should. I also have the "None" box working by unchecking the other boxes, but that doesn't trigger the fields to hide like I was hoping.

Any suggestions?

TLDR: DIV fields shouldn't be seen until the corresponding box is checked. All DIV fields should disappear if the "None" box is checked.

```js
$('#checkboxes-0').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $('#blank_co').fadeIn('slow');
  else
    $('#blank_co').fadeOut('slow');

});

$('#checkboxes-1').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $('#fresh_co').fadeIn('slow');
  else
    $('#fresh_co').fadeOut('slow');

});

$('#checkboxes-2').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $('#marine_co').fadeIn('slow');
  else
    $('#marine_co').fadeOut('slow');

});

$('#checkboxes-3').change(function() {
  if (this.checked)
    $('#rain_co').fadeIn('slow');
  else
    $('#rain_co').fadeOut('slow');
});

var $others = $('input[name="checkboxes"]').not('#checkboxes-4')
$('#checkboxes-4').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $others.prop('checked', false)
  }
});
$others.change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#checkboxes-4').prop('checked', false)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">

  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">
    Select any desired backgrounds:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-0" type="checkbox" value="blanks">
          Blanks
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-1" type="checkbox" value="fresh">
          Fresh Water
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-2">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-2" type="checkbox" value="marine">
          Marine Water
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-3">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-3" type="checkbox" value="rain">
          Rain
        </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" type="checkbox" value="none">
          None
        </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="blank_co" div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="blankbg">Blanks cutoff: (1-99)</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input name="blankbg" class="form-control input-md" id="blankbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="fresh_co" div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="freshbg">Fresh water cutoff: (1-99)</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input name="freshbg" class="form-control input-md" id="freshbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="marine_co" div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="marinebg">Marine water cutoff: (1-99)</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input name="marinebg" class="form-control input-md" id="marinebg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="rain_co" div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rainbg">Rain water cutoff: (1-99)</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <input name="rainbg" class="form-control input-md" id="rainbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You use the `.change()` method of the the checkboxes, which triggers the given function after it's value has changed. Thus you have to click them initially.

Comment: I'll update my question shortly.  I added style="display:none" to the DIV blocks which defaults them to not show unless the checkbox is checked.  But that doesn't fix the "None" box behavior.

Comment: How should the input be when the page load, displayed or hidden?

Comment: What should happens when "None" is *unchecked*? Should *all* the form groups appear or only those that disappeared when "None" was *checked*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all the `<div>` elements containing the inputs first, and then when the `None` checkbox box is ticked, you invoke each `<div>` to fade out as required.

```html
<html>
    <title>
    </title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
        <div class="form-group">
    
    
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">
    Select any desired backgrounds:</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-0" type="checkbox" value="blanks">
          Blanks
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-1" type="checkbox" value="fresh">
          Fresh Water
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-2">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-2" type="checkbox" value="marine">
          Marine Water
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-3">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-3" type="checkbox" value="rain">
          Rain
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
          <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" type="checkbox" value="none">
          None
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div id="blank_co" div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="blankbg">Blanks cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input name="blankbg" class="form-control input-md" id="blankbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">
    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div id="fresh_co" div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="freshbg">Fresh water cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input name="freshbg" class="form-control input-md" id="freshbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">
    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div id="marine_co" div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="marinebg">Marine water cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input name="marinebg" class="form-control input-md" id="marinebg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">
    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div id="rain_co" div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rainbg">Rain water cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input name="rainbg" class="form-control input-md" id="rainbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">
    
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkboxes-0').change(function(){
            if(this.checked)
                $('#blank_co').fadeIn('slow');
            else
                $('#blank_co').fadeOut('slow');
    
        });
    
          $('#checkboxes-1').change(function(){
            if(this.checked)
                $('#fresh_co').fadeIn('slow');
            else
                $('#fresh_co').fadeOut('slow');
    
        });
    
          $('#checkboxes-2').change(function(){
            if(this.checked)
                $('#marine_co').fadeIn('slow');
            else
                $('#marine_co').fadeOut('slow');
    
        });
    
          $('#checkboxes-3').change(function(){
            if(this.checked)
                $('#rain_co').fadeIn('slow');
            else
                $('#rain_co').fadeOut('slow');
      });
    
        var $others = $('input[name="checkboxes"]').not('#checkboxes-4')
        var $othersWrappers = $('div[id$="_co"]')
    $('#checkboxes-4').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $others.prop('checked', false)
            $othersWrappers.each(function( index ) {
              $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
        }
    });
    $others.change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#checkboxes-4').prop('checked', false)
        }
    })
    
    
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: This did the trick. I was thinking that by changing the checked status, it would trigger the listeners, but i guess that isn't the case.    @Laurent.S are you talking about the checkboxes change function?

Comment: @Steve I see what you were thinking. The reason why that didn't work is that the onchange event is only fired when the user changes the selected value manually, not when the value is changed programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need.

```html
<body>
    <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
    <div class="form-group">


<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">
Select any desired backgrounds:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-0">
      <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-0" type="checkbox" value="blanks">
      Blanks
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
      <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-1" type="checkbox" value="fresh">
      Fresh Water
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-2">
      <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-2" type="checkbox" value="marine">
      Marine Water
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-3">
      <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-3" type="checkbox" value="rain">
      Rain
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-4">
      <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-4" type="checkbox" value="none">
      None
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="blank_co" div class="form-group hide">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="blankbg">Blanks cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input name="blankbg" class="form-control input-md" id="blankbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="fresh_co" div class="form-group hide">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="freshbg">Fresh water cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input name="freshbg" class="form-control input-md" id="freshbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="marine_co" div class="form-group hide">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="marinebg">Marine water cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input name="marinebg" class="form-control input-md" id="marinebg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div id="rain_co" div class="form-group hide">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rainbg">Rain water cutoff: (1-99)</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input name="rainbg" class="form-control input-md" id="rainbg" required="" type="text" placeholder="" value="10">

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkboxes-0').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#blank_co').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('#blank_co').fadeOut('slow');

    });

      $('#checkboxes-1').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#fresh_co').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('#fresh_co').fadeOut('slow');

    });

      $('#checkboxes-2').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#marine_co').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('#marine_co').fadeOut('slow');

    });

      $('#checkboxes-3').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('#rain_co').fadeIn('slow');
        else
            $('#rain_co').fadeOut('slow');
  });

    var $others = $('input[name="checkboxes"]').not('#checkboxes-4')
$('#checkboxes-4').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $others.prop('checked', false)
    }
});
$others.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#checkboxes-4').prop('checked', false)
    }
})


});
</script>
 
 <script>

    //hide "div.hide" if "none" checked
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkboxes-4').change(function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $('div.hide').fadeOut('slow');
        else
            $('div.hide').fadeIn('slow');

    });
});
</script>
</body>
```